# Angualr signalR socket returns same value everytime I change route

Tags: angular, sockets, websocket, signalr

I'm using angular signalR socket and reciving data from socket everytime I click on button
I'm listening to socket in the ngOnInit() of component
The problem is when I change the route the socket returns the same data again .

myComponent.ts

```js
..
ngOnInit(): void {

       console.log("hi")
       this._hubConnection.start().then(() => {

                console.log("connected to socket")

              }).catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
```

every time I change the route the console keeps showing connected to socket the `ngOnInit()` is working only once because "`Hi`" came from `console.log("hi")` shows only once so the problem in signalR socket

}